# Inheritance of class __init__ method

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, superclass

I am fairly new to OOP and want to simplify some of my classes which use the same `__init__` and the same methods.

For the following to classes I want the `CreateConstructionObject` class to inherit the `__init__` method and the `CreateObject`, `SelectObject` and `DeleteObject` methods from the `CreateIDFObject` class,  while keeping the `SetObjectValue` method from the  `CreateConstructionObject` class.

Original classes:

```
class CreateIDFObject:
    def __init__(self, filename, object_type, json_path, fields):
        self.CreateObject(filename, object_type)
        self.SelectObject(filename, object_type)
        try:
            self.SetObjectValue(json_path, fields)
        except Exception:
            self.DeleteObject(filename, object_type)

    def CreateObject(self, filename, object_type):
        self.filename = filename.newidfobject(object_type)

    def SelectObject(self, filename, object_type):
        self.object = filename.idfobjects[object_type][-1]

    def DeleteObject(self, filename, object_type):
        filename.popidfobject(object_type,-1)
        print(f'Object: {object_type} was deleted, due to missing data inputs.')

    def SetObjectValue(self, json_path, fields):
        for field in fields:
            if type(json_path[field]) is bool:
                if json_path[field] == True:
                    self.object[field] = "Yes"

                elif json_path[field] == False:
                    self.object[field] = "No"

            else:
                self.object[field] = json_path[field]
```

---

```
class CreateConstructionObject:
    def __init__(self, filename, object_type, json_path, fields):
        self.CreateObject(filename, object_type)
        self.SelectObject(filename, object_type)
        try:
            self.SetObjectValue(json_path, fields)
        except Exception:
            self.DeleteObject(filename, object_type)

    def CreateObject(self, filename, object_type):
        self.filename = filename.newidfobject(object_type)

    def SelectObject(self, filename, object_type):
        self.object = filename.idfobjects[object_type][-1]

    def DeleteObject(self, filename, object_type):
        filename.popidfobject(object_type,-1)
        print(f'Object: {object_type} was deleted, due to missing data inputs.')

    def SetObjectValue(self, json_path, fields):
        for field in fields:
            self.object[field] = json_path[field]

            for i in range(len(json_path["Layers"])):
                if i == 0:
                    self.object["Outside_Layer"] = json_path["Layers"][i][f"Layer{i+1}"]
                else:
                    self.object[f"Layer_{i+1}"] = json_path["Layers"][i][f"Layer{i+1}"]
```

I have currently done as follows without any luck:

```
from .CreateIDFObject import CreateIDFObject

class CreateConstructionObject(CreateIDFObject):
    def __init__(self, filename, object_type, json_path, fields):
        super().__init__(filename, object_type, json_path, fields)

    def SetObjectValue(self, json_path, fields):
        for field in fields:
            self.object[field] = json_path[field]

            for i in range(len(json_path["Layers"])):
                if i == 0:
                    self.object["Outside_Layer"] = json_path["Layers"][i][f"Layer{i+1}"]
                else:
                    self.object[f"Layer_{i+1}"] = json_path["Layers"][i][f"Layer{i+1}"]
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing while subclassing?

Comment: I use these classes and their methods in a large scripts to parse data from a JSON file to an EnergyPlus Input Data FIle (IDF). The CreateConstructionObject does not perform the intended tasks when I use inheritance. Don´t know if this clarifies the issue.

Comment: What you've written is correct, though you should just delete the `__init__` in `CreateConstructionObject` since it doesn't do anything differently from the parent's `__init__`.

Comment: Side-note: While you're doing live development, I'd suggest defining both classes in the same file; `reload` isn't transitive, so if you change `CreateIDFObject.py`, and want the changes to be seen in an interactive session without exiting and restarting, you'd have to `reload(CreateIDFObject)`, then `reload(NameOfModuleWithCreateConstructionObject)` for the changes to take effect (do it in the wrong order, or only do the former, and `CreateConstructionObject` inherits from the stale version of `CreateIDFObject`).

Comment: @FrederikSeeberg: You're going to need to be more specific in any event; a [MCVE] requires example input, expected output, and observed output. "It's wrong" is pretty useless when we don't know what right is, and how it's departing from correct.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mre] that shows it "not working".

Comment: Off-topic: I suggest that you follow the [PEP 8 recommendation for module names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) and make them all-lowercase (and maybe shorter) — i.e. **don't** name the file the second class is in `CreateIDFObject.py`.